What were the last five moves?
Here is yet another retrograde chess puzzle - this time a bit more on the trickier side, I believe. I'm quite happy with how this one turned out, so please have a try if you like :)
What were the last four five (half-)moves that lead to the position below?

As usual, please share your reasoning in your answer and provide a (sketch of a) proof game to reach this position. Have fun! :)

Note: The original puzzle was flawed - it had several unintended solutions that I had missed. This newer version "kills" the old intended solution and instead fixes one of the previously unintended ones to (hopefully this time!) being unique. I'm very sorry for the inconvenience - but I'm convinced that most of the necessary deductions carry over to the new version.
For reference, here is the original flawed puzzle:

I still quite enjoy the intended solution of this one - to find it you may just assume that every single one of Benjamin Wangs (original) deductions is correct and proceed from there :)

I don’t think this layout is possible…

I think I have solved all issues except the rot13(grzcb vffhr ng gur raq) :(

@BenjaminWang it doesn’t seem possible how the black king can reach g2… with the white bishop being on a2

@PDT from the A file. I'll post a partial solution later

I know the king can enter on the left but any way disallows the positioning of the bishop on a2…

@PDT rot13(Gnxr jvgu gur juvgr n-cnja ba o4, zbir gur ovfubc gb n2 naq gur oynpx xvat gb n4. Gura whfg o3+ Xn3 naq gur xvat ragref ivn o2?)

@PDT please check the partial solution

Ah I see I didn’t realise the rook didn’t have to be under promoted mb

One complete solution
Copy paste into https://lichess.org/paste to see it
1. Nf3 Nf6 2. Ne5 Ne4 3. Nf3 Ng5 4. Ne5 Nh3 5. gxh3 Nc6 6. Bg2 Na5 7. Bd5 Nb3 8. Kf1 Nxc1 9. Kg2 Nb3 10. Kf3 Nc5 11. Nd3 Ne6 12. Nb4 Nc5 13. Na6 bxa6 14. Nc3 g6 15. Qg1 Bh6 16. Qg4 Be3 17. fxe3 Rb8 18. Rhg1 Rb4 19. Qh5 Rd4 20. exd4 Bb7 21. Kf4 Qb8 22. Be6 Be4 23. Rg5 Na4 24. Rag1 Qb5 25. R1g4 Qc5 26. dxc5 Kd8 27. Nd1 Kc8 28. Nc3 Kb7 29. Nd1 Kc6 30. Ne3 Kb5 31. Nd1 Rb8 32. Ne3 Ka5 33. Rd5 Rb3 34. Rd4 Ra3 35. Rb4 Rb3 36. Rb8 Ra3 37. Rh8 Nc3 38. Kg5 Na4 39. Kh6 Nc3 40. Kg7 Na4 41. Kf8 Nc3 42. Ke8 Na4 43. Kd8 Nc3 44. Kc8 Na4 45. Nd1 Rb3 46. Qd5 Rb6 47. cxb6+ Kb4 48. b7 Nc3 49. b8=B Ka4 50. Qa8 Nb5 51. Ne3 Nc3 52. Nd5 Nb5 53. Rg5 Bh1 54. Rh5 Nd4 55. Kb7 Nc6 56. Rg5 Nb4 57. a3 Bg2 58. axb4 Bh1 59. Bf5 Bg2 60. Bd3 Bh1 61. Bc4 Bg2 62. Ba2 Bh1 63. b3+ Ka3 64. Re5 Kb2 65. Re4 Kc1 66. Re5 Kd1 67. Re4 Ke1 68. Re5 Kf1 69. Rf5+ Kg2 70. Rf3 h6 71. Rh7 Kg1 72. Rf1+ Kg2 73. Rb1 Kf2 74. Rb2 Kg2 75. Nb6 axb6 *

So the last moves are WRb2 BKg2 WNb6 Baxb6 (last move) (W=white, B=black). There are multiple ways to finish the job.
This solution uses pretty much the same reasoning as the previous solution, except without an assumption after Point (4).
Previous partial solution
The reason that it is not a complete solution is that there are tempo issues near the end. I will try to include only rigorous deductions in the following section, so as not to mislead anyone. The statements in later sections are speculations.
Previous partial deductions
Some of these deductions seem absurd. But as long as it is not absolutely impossible, we must follow the trail to get to the end. (W = White, B = Black) First note that White is missing 3 things while Black is missing 6.

Black King cannot enter from the bottom right because of the pawn structure. Therefore it enters from the bottom left.
The only way for the Black King to enter from the bottom left is (roughly) the following sequence. Assume no pawn pushes yet from the bottom left. Wa3, Wa3xb4, BKa4, WBa2, WBb1, Wb3+, BKa3, b2, c1, d1, e1, f1, ... (Note that there is one capture here)
Notice that bullet point (2) prevents WBc1 from coming out, or even existing during the process (i.e. it is captured on its starting square). Therefore WBb8 must be promoted(!)
Point (3) means the White Rook in the top right is not promoted. So there are two pawn captures (capturing two White Knights). Now all of White's pieces are accounted for.

In (4) I prematurely assumed that these two captures are in the top right.

Point (2) captures one Black piece. There's another Black piece captured on a3. So the f2 pawn captures the remaining 4 Black pieces on its way to promotion on b8.
Point (5) means all Black pieces are accounted for.
Point (4) means that the White King enters from the top left. The only way to do this is via a6 then b7.
Point (4) and (5) mean that the Black f8 Bishop needed to get out (and not die on the starting square). So the order of the top-right pawn captures in (4) is g7xh6 first, and then h7xg6.
Point (8), as well as the presence of the White Rook on h7, means that h7xg6 cannot be the last move of the game. This, together with Point (6), means that Black has tempo issues near the end.

Previous tricks and notes
I used a7-a6 to gain a tempo for Black near the end, but it is not enough, as one more is required.
In theory, the White Rook can enter from the bottom left, but I think that just makes it harder to avoid the mutual check between the Queen and Bishop.
Previous incorrect answer to the last few plies
This doesn't work because of mutual check issues between the Queen and Bishop.
- WRb1-b2
- BPa7-a6
- WRf1-b1
- BKg1-g2
- WR?1-f1+

Previous attempt:
This attempt will end up one tempo short. Please just take it as an illustrative reference of my deductions.
Copy paste into https://lichess.org/paste to see it.
1. Nf3 Nf6 2. Ne5 Ne4 3. Nf3 Ng5 4. Ne5 Nh3 5. gxh3 Nc6 6. Bg2 Na5 7. Bd5 Nb3 8. Kf1 Nxc1 9. Kg2 Nb3 10. Kf3 Nc5 11. Ng4 Na6 12. Nh6 gxh6 13. Qg1 Bg7 14. Qg4 Bd4 15. Qf4 Be3 16. fxe3 Kf8 17. Qh4 Kg7 18. Nc3 Qg8 19. Qh5 Kf6 20. Rag1 Qg4+ 21. Kf2 Qd4 22. exd4 b6 23. Na4 Bb7 24. Nc3 Bc6 25. Na4 Rag8 26. Nc3 Bb5 27. Bf3 Rg5 28. Na4 Rc5 29. dxc5 Rb8 30. c6 Rb7 31. cxb7 Nc5 32. Rg7 Na6 33. b8=B Nc5 34. Qd5 Na6 35. Qa8 Nc5 36. Ke3 Ne6 37. Nc3 Bc6 38. Kd3 Be4+ 39. Kc4 Bf5 40. Kb5 Be4 41. Ka6 Bf5 42. Kb7 Nf8 43. Nd5+ Ke6 44. Ne3 Ng6 45. Ng2 Ne5 46. Nh4 Ng6 47. Rg1 Ne5 48. R1g4 Ng6 49. Rc4 Ne5 50. Rc5 Ng6 51. Rc6+ Ke5 52. Rd6 Nf8 53. Re6+ Kd4 54. Rd6+ Kc4 55. Re6 Kb4 56. Rd6 Ka4 57. Bg4 Be4+ 58. Kc8 Bh1 59. Ng6 Ne6 60. a3 Nd4 61. Re6 Nc6 62. Rd6 Nb4 63. axb4 Bg2 64. Be6 Bh1 65. Ba2 Bg2 66. Bb1 Bh1 67. b3+ Ka3 68. Ba2 Kb2 69. Bb1 Kc1 70. Ba2 Kd1 71. Bb1 Ke1 72. Ba2 Kf1 73. Bb1 Kg1 74. Ba2 hxg6 75. Rh7 Kf1 76. Rd5 Kg1 77. Rd3 Kf1 78. Rf3+ Kg2 79. Kb7 *


There is a (very) small gap here in point 4: Why are the black pawn captures necessarily on the right? Other than that, this looks really good so far! Keep at it and I'm sure you'll figute it out :)

Oh, I realize that I missed this, too (it was impossible for a previous version but apparently I forgot to check that the deduction carried over) Unfortunately that means there are several solutions now! I'm sorry :/

@TimSeifert yes I suppose the WR might enter from the top left. But at this time I don't see how that can save a tempo, since the g7 pawn still needs to be pushed to let the f8 bishop out.

Done! Thanks for the hint.

Thanks a lot and great job! I'm so sorry for messing this up - I have just now finished a fix, that (hopefully) only has one solution this time! :)

But if you're interested: The original intended solution actually worked with the pawn captures on the right (and was quite neat, I think). If you want a further challenge, you might still want to think about it as if all your deductions were right :)

Yea I thought it must be possible as it was quite close and probably intended. Thank you!

Since I messed the puzzle up the first time around and there already is an excellent answer to the previous version, I'm going to share my thoughts on the new version and the previously intended solution for anyone interested. (Please let me know if this is not a good idea for any reason.)

 Both puzzles run parallel for the most part until the end. The first major deduction for both is that the white bishop in the top region must be the promoted f-pawn. This can be found out by consideration of the black kings entry route: The pawn structure on the right forbids his entry there, so he must have come from the left. Now, observe that the presence of the white bishop on a2 implies that the pawn on b3 did not originate on a2. (Otherwise, the entry of the bishop would have been permanently blocked.) Therefore, it must be the b-pawn, which moved into place once the bishop had already entered, which means that the a-pawn also must have already moved. Thus, the only possible entryway for the black king was via a3-b2. Since the a-pawn must have already moved when a3 was not under threat, the only option is that it was already on b4, meaning the king came from a4-a3 before. Now, this move is only possible if white had played b2-b3 immediately before. But that implies that the bishop from c1 never had a chance to exit its home square before this sequence. Since it also cannot be present during it (otherwise ka4-a3 was illegal), it must have been captured sometime before. Thus, the bishop in the top must be promoted, in fact the promoted f-pawn.


 As a consequence, every other white piece must be real. This makes the entry of the rook(s) and the king into the top region interesting: For the rooke to enter, there must have been an open file - hence, some pair of black (next-to-)flank pawns both captured to reach their final position. This implies that the white king must have entered from the other side, where a next-to-flank pawn had already moved but the flank pawn had not. While we cannot conclude from here, which side did which maneuver, we can conclude that the f-pawn did not promote on the right, since no option for blacks a- and b-pawns allows for its entry after that. Thus, it must have promoted on b8.


 We can now tally up the black captures: One capture by the a-pawn, one by the g-pawn and at least 4 by the f-pawn on its way over. This accounts for all the missing black pieces already. Also note that both the a- and g-pawn captures are well in the past and happened even before the black king entered the white premises. Thus, the most recent white capture was by the f-pawn, which is still at least 3 moves back (not even considering any checking issues in the position).


 The white captures are more straightforward, the c1-bishop was taken on its home square and the knights were eaten by blacks pawns to let in the rook(s).


 Now we are ready to face the final position. The mutual "retro-pin" of the kings can only be resolved by either moving first the queen and then the white king out of the way, or by blocking the line of sight somehow. In particular, until either of these happen, black can only retract pawn moves, and also only two of them, since any more would (for one thing) block in their bishop from exiting well before.

Here, the two positions diverge. I will first lay out the newer version:

 At least two white pieces need to (un)move before one of the left black pawns can (un)move. In particular, if it is now whites turn, then black must have just moved a pawn on the right, before which there is no more black move (even an uncaptured white knight cannot reach the diagonal in time). Thus, white moved last. If that move was not Rc8-b8, we have the same issue as before, so that must have been the last move. Before that, black must have moved a pawn on the right. Again, an uncaptured knight would be too slow, so black needs to have one more pawn move available. Thus, the previous white move must have been Bb8-a7, allowing a black pawn to have come from a7. Now, did the black pawn captures happen on the left or the right? If they did on the right, then we are lost - the white knight uncaptured on the last move cannot reach the diagonal in time, so that black can have no more possible move before that. Thus, the knights were captured on the left - which thankfully leaves just a single move time for the just uncaptured knight on b6 to come from d5 and thus allows blacks king to unstep out of this arrangement and solve the tempo issue. This second-to-last pawn move being a capture also fixes the last one: Since the pawns on the right did not capture, the last one of them to move was the h-pawn, so that the full sequence of the last five plies was (in chronological order): Nd5-b6, a7xb6, Bb8-a7, h7-h6, Rc8-b8.


 For the original puzzle I had missed that the black pawn captures can have been on the left. The intended solution proceeded with the assumption that they were on the right. The same tempo considerations lead to the only possibilty being a white knight blocking the main diagonal before being captured on g6. The only way that can have happened was therefore ending with the sequence N?-e5, a7-a6, Ne5-g6, h7xg6, Rh8-h7, with the last four plies being uniquely determined.


 For both versions, it is then not too difficult to build a proof game from here. In the first you just have to take care to leave enough space for the white king and rooks to shuffle themselves into position before letting the f-pawn in.

